# Simple Android / Java Countdown App

Tags: java, android, date

I'm trying to create a Countdown app for an event. I will need to subtract the current time from the future event time, and display the difference in Days, Hours, minutes and seconds.

So far I have managed to make an app that displays the time with this code below. What do I need to add to it to display the time until say Christmas, for example? Preferably the results would change in real time.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

    text.setText(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
  thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,25);
  thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH,7); // 0-11 so 1 less
  thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1985);

  Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();



long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - thatDay.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis
```

Here's an approximation...

```
long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: sir...,.how can we add ,can you give any example

Comment: means http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701393/android-how-to-make-calender-like-countdown-clock

Comment: i have used calender with timer its working..,but i want t o move it in opposite way.like thishttp://www.timeanddate.com/countdown/generic?iso=20140320T1257&p0=418&msg=Countdown+till+Spring+2014

Comment: see this http://www.timeanddate.com/countdown/generic?iso=20140320T1257&p0=418&msg=Countdown+till+Spring+2014

Comment: i want to do like this,currently my timer is working in forward mode.,i wnat to move it in reverse mode

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47379/discussion-between-rajshree-and-digvesh-patel)

Comment: here is the link of chat

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html
There are several support methods for caluclating time distances.